# Assign completion flag with factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot figure it out how can i make a factory that sets completion flag for a value of an object . I have an object like this

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}
```

Here i wana use first value with key key1 and after the operartion on this value is done i want to set this value as completed or success or anything just like a flag to identify for future use.

Comment: Please put working code so that would be better to help you

Comment: ok @Jigar7521 i will.

Comment: You don't want to keep the initial value?

Answer (score 1):

`var smthing={"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"};`  is similar to PHP's array system.

To use the field simply use like `smthing.key1` which will return `"value1"`. And you can affect a value like a normal variable: `smthing.key1=somethingYouWant;`

```js
var smthing={"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"};
window.alert("key1 : " + smthing.key1);
smthing.key1="complete"; // or anything you want
window.alert("key1 : " + smthing.key1);

// You can even delete it 
delete smthing.key1;
window.alert("key1 : " + smthing.key1);
```